# scala.io.Source not finding an existing file

Tags: java, scala, io, playframework, filenotfoundexception

This piece of scala code:

```
val file = new File(".")
assert(file.exists == true)
assert(file.getAbsolutePath.length > 0)
println(scala.io.Source.fromFile(file).getLines)
```

Throws:

```
FileNotFoundException: . (No such file or directory) (FileInputStream.java:120)
```

While making the `scala.io.Source.fromFile` call. How is this possible and how can I fix it?

PS: This is in the context of a playframework app test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe because:

```
assert(file.isDirectory)
```

passes as well? You cannot really open a directory and read it, you can only open files. BTW on my machine the error is more descriptive:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: . (Is a directory)
```

Tested on:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_26"
$ scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.9.1.final
```

Comment: Good point, but doing `new File("./FileName.java")` doesn't solve the issue either :(

Comment: @PabloFernandez: you're saying that `file.exists` is true but still you get `FileNotFoundException`? What about calling `new FileInputStream(file)`?

Comment: sorry I had another error on my app that was causing the issue. Your answer is correct